# Google Apps Script: Use the sidebar to create a new sheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a new sheet in my spreadsheet with the sidebar. I'm new to working with the sidebar so I'm not sure how to do it.

Code.gs:

```
function createSheet(sheetName) {
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)  
  if (!sheet) {
    ss.insertSheet('Lookup: ' + sheetName)
  }
}
```

Page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>Create Partial Vlookup Table</h3>
    
    <input id="myData">    
    <button onclick="createLookup()">Click</button>        
    
    <script>          
      function createLookup(){
        var myData = document.getElementById('myData').value
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createSheet(myData))
      }
    </script>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get with this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to insert new sheet in the active Spreadsheet using the sidebar.

### Modification points:

- In order to run the function at Google Apps Script side, please modify `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(createSheet(myData))` to `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function).createSheet(myData)`.
- In your script of `createSheet`, it seems that `ss` is not declared.

When your script is modified with above points, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### HTML & Javascript side:

In this case, please modify `createLookup` as follows.

```
function createLookup(){
  var myData = document.getElementById('myData').value;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(alert).createSheet(myData);  // Modified
}
```

#### Google Apps Script side:

```
function createSheet(sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  // Added
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) {
    ss.insertSheet('Lookup: ' + sheetName);
  }
  return "ok";  // Added
}
```

- By above modification, when the button on the side bar by inputting a value is clicked, a new sheet is inserted in the active Spreadsheet. And, `ok` is returned and you can see it at the alert dialog on the browser.
- When you want the script for opening the side bar, how about the following script?

  ```
    function openSidebar() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Page"));
    }
  ```

### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need :D